# Dynamics CRM Plug-in Configuration Manager Utility

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-365-ce-onpremises

There is a tool called Plug-in Configuration Manager Utility that was on codeplex (https://pluginconfigmgrutil.codeplex.com/)

Since codepleax is not available anymore I am wondering if someone has this tool and can share it with me please.

Comment: looks like the author was Yaniv Arditi (https://www.linkedin.com/in/yanivarditi/) https://yanivrdt.wordpress.com/2016/07/15/plug-in-configuration-manager-utility/ try to contact him directly

Comment: Yes. I tried to contact him but he is not responding. I really appreciate it if someone has downloded it and can share it with me.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://temmyraharjo.wordpress.com/2021/12/11/dynamics-crm-how-to-get-the-secure-and-unsecure-configurations-list/) can help you build your own tool.